# Show the "review" link in the topbar on beta sites while Site Self-Evaluation review is enabled for a few days

Tags: feature-request, review, beta-sites, top-bar, site-evaluation

If I don't have an [Access Review Queues](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) privilege on beta sites (i.e. less than 350 reputation), the "review" link does not appear in the top-bar. There is a review queue in beta sites named "[Site Self-Evaluation](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval)" review which is enabled for a few days which can be reviewed by users even without having an "Access Review Queues" privilege (I don't know exactly how many reputation is required to access this review queue but at least I can access it with 101 reputation). So if I don't see a review link on the top-bar how can I know that this review queue is enabled right now which I can review?

See this picture says what I mean:

> [image]

Isn't it a good idea to show the "review" link on the top-bar for a few days (i.e. while "Site Self-Evaluation" review queue is enabled) to all user who can access this review queue?

---

<sup>Note: Site Self-Evaluation is very important phase for any beta site. Community evaluates what will Google users' first impression be. The reviews of new users of the site (i.e. users with less reputation) are important. If they can't review just because they don't have a review link, it's a damage of the beta site itself.</sup>

Comment: Perhaps I'm totally wrong, but isn't there a 'featured post' in the box in the top right of the page when there is a site quality review? I always clicked that link (or the link in the corresponding meta post) rather than going through the review link.

Comment: @jmac - You are correct! There is a Community bulletin where we see "featured posts/links". It gives both meta and review links. http://i.stack.imgur.com/MaSlf.png. I didn't notice that. Happy now. Thanks.

Comment: @jmac - It would be nice if you add this as an answer. This satisfies my purpose of asking this question.

Comment: done and done. I pilfered your freehand circles though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is a site self-evaluation, the community bulletin in the top right has links both to the review, and to the meta post:

[image]